# Advantages of Dict over OrderedDict

Tags: python, dictionary

I find it annoying that Python dictionaries do not store keys in insertion order. Recently, I've started using OrderedDict, which is more convenient to use since it covers this drawback (for example, iterating over columns of a CSV file where the column order is supposed to match the key order of a dictionary).

That said, are there any distinct advantages that a dictionary has over an OrderedDict? If so, what are they?

Comment: I dislike the string representation of `OrderDict`s, so often convert them to regular `dict`s for display purposes. There also must be some extra overhead for maintaining the order, put that the price of admission for the feature (and frankly I've never noticed it).

Comment: Note that in python 3.5, `OrderedDict` will be a builtin type and will be used for some things (e.g. `**kwargs`).

Comment: There is a general rule about (container) classes - not just for Python: more features => more overhead, more memory => slower. All asuming comparable container types, of course. It's up to you what you need and how much drawback you can/want to accept. As in real life: nothing is for free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A dictionary is a simpler data structure that takes up less space and is a bit faster. It only needs to maintain a hash table, while an `OrderedDict` maintains both a hash table and a linked list.

If you don't care about the order of keys, go with the simpler option.

Also not to be overlooked, there's language level support for dicts. It's easy to type `{k1: v1, k2: v2}`. That's another win for dicts. An unfair one, perhaps, but there you go.